# Resize iframe & textarea in reverse directions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `textarea` and `iframe` whose sizes should change dynamically and in reverse directions. I'd like to achive this effect without using a `frameset` or jQuery plugin. Here's the result of my attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Resize</title>
    <style>
        textarea,
        iframe {
            display: block;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        textarea {
            background: green;
            resize: none;
        }
        iframe {
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="slide" oninput="resize();" onchange="resize();" type="range" min="0" max="400" value="200">
    <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
    <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
    <script>
        var slide = document.getElementById("slide");
        var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
        var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");

        function resize() {
            var slideValue = slide.value;
            textarea.style.height = slideValue + "px";
            iframe.style.height = 400 - slideValue + "px";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RainLover/EY4mR/24/)

I wonder if you could review my code and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps add `overflow:hidden;` to the CSS of the `textarea` and `iframe`, and add `scrolling="no"` as an attribute of the HTML `iframe` element: because otherwise, a scrollbar will appear when the slider is very big or very small.

Maybe a scrollbar is what you want (for usability); but a scrollbar makes a small visual artifact in an empty textbox or iframe, when the element is shorter than one line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this `textarea` isn't going to be empty. If I add `overflow:hidden;` to the `textarea` and remove its scrolling functionality, then how can I insert and access a long string of text?

Comment: @RainLover The scrollbar was a minor (perhaps unhelpful) answer: it was the only thing I found to comment on or criticize. Apart from that the code looks good to me: simple and easy to read. You could perhaps add a comment in the code to explain what functionality it is implementing. Do you have any specific questions/concerns about he code you posted?

Comment: Nothing in particular. Just wanted to make sure my coding is right and if there's a better approach to achieve the same effect. Thanks anyway! :)